# Use typescript to create union object of keys in objects

Tags: typescript, object, generics, union

I have the following object:

```
const myObject = {
  one: {
    fixed: {
      a: 1
    }
  },
  two: {
    fixed: {
      b: true
    }
  },
  three: {
    fixed: {
      c: 'foo'
    }
  }
}
```

How can I use this object, to create a type equivalent to the following:

```
type MyUnionType = {
  a: number
  b: boolean
  c: string
}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
type MyObject = typeof myObject;

type MyUnionType = {
    [T in keyof MyObject as keyof MyObject[T]["fixed"]]: MyObject[T]["fixed"][keyof MyObject[T]["fixed"]]
}
```

From the varying top level properties as a type parameter (eg (`one`), it first extracts the key of the nested object (eg `a` or `b`) and then (verbosely) accesses the nested value associated with that key.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you:) I made a playground from your answer. Check it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDDOBgFwHEkwBmAlgB4YAmlRNNAhpQIzUkAvtUEAaalADuIdgLpNWsziRSUoAJwCuGOcKHiSUABbqMFKpwbM2F5cEoByWiBAPdIwsMJQEABwwwALLI6Fi4MD7+ILTwIZjYANyE3n4BwQCqYPTgACqpMHgcNADaOTD0YDAA1hgI0UFxYTBcENW19cGo8VClALrFAERWrAO9vZSdodh9g8Mso8U1dTGT3TNDCvNjnsmgkLCImdlgef68EwhHufmF1DwwvAYwqnRcADYQGE-2ME4ubl49tBYlcTqkAEwXUGnAK3Ej3By8ByiGAAelRr3oH2oL1o70+30czlcO0IQIOlyy138AGYoVSwf4CrZ7o8YDi+Cj0ZjsSQfn8SYDwMDDgyYXSGtCbizOeyVJQ8R8vtQforPmiMXisRAdkA).